# Prevent col-md-3 sidebars from scrolling @media min-width 992px

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I only want the central part of the website `col-md-6` to scroll while on a medium screen like facebook. How do I get this to happen? The `sidebar one` and `sidebar two`in the jsfiddle should remain fixed. my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/idwapro/26q8ksvz/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by using css `position` property

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
}

.side1,
.side2 {
  position: -webkit-sticky!important;
  position: sticky!important;
  top: 0;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<!-- ADD THE CLASS layout-top-nav TO REMOVE THE SIDEBAR. -->

<body class="hold-transition skin-black-light layout-top-nav">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <header class="main-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="../../index2.html" class="navbar-brand">Tester</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
          </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-left" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="navbar-search-input" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- Full Width Column -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header"></section>

        <section class="content">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-3 side1">
              <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header">
                  <h3 class="box-title">side bar one</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">

                  <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-xs-6 main1 ">
              <div class="box box-widget">
                <div class="box-body">
                  <!-- post text -->
                  <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at</p>

                  <p>the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                  <!-- post text -->
                  <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at</p>

                  <p>the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                  <!-- post text -->
                  <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at</p>

                  <p>the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                  <!-- post text -->
                  <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at</p>

                  <p>the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                  <!-- post text -->
                  <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at</p>

                  <p>the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                  <!-- post text -->
                  <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at</p>

                  <p>the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                  <!-- post text -->
                  <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at</p>

                  <p>the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                  <!-- post text -->
                  <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at</p>

                  <p>the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                  <!-- post text -->
                  <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at</p>

                  <p>the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                  <!-- post text -->
                  <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at</p>

                  <p>the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-xs-3 side2">
              <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header">
                  <h3 class="box-title">side bar two</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">

                  <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </div>
 

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you this is perfect, i only increased the `top` value

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing issue in IE and old browsers, use this JS instead 'position: sticky' CSS. **Please open below code in FULL VIEW**.

```js
(function($) {
 $.fn.sticky = function( options ) {
  var settings = $.extend({
   stickyTop : 0,
   stickyBottom : 0,
   widthLimit: 0,
   stickyClass: false,
   stickyParent: false
  }, options);
  return this.each( function() {
   var $ele = $(this);
   var eleTop, eleLeft, eleBottom, eleParBot, eleWid, winWid
   var r = function(){
    eleTop = $ele.offset().top - settings.stickyTop;
    eleLeft = $ele.offset().left;
    eleBottom = $ele.offset().top + $ele.innerHeight() + settings.stickyBottom;
    $eleParent = $ele.parents(settings.stickyParent) || $ele.parent();
    eleParBot = $eleParent.offset().top + $eleParent.innerHeight();
    eleWid = $ele.innerWidth();
    winWid = $(window).outerWidth();
    f();
   }
   var f = function(){
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(winTop >= eleTop && winWid > settings.widthLimit){
     $ele.css({
      'position': 'fixed',
      'top': settings.stickyTop,
      'left': eleLeft,
      'width': eleWid
     });
     if (settings.stickyClass != false) {
      $ele.addClass(settings.stickyClass);
     }
     if(winTop >= eleParBot-$ele.innerHeight()-settings.stickyTop+settings.stickyBottom){
      $ele.css('top', (winTop - eleParBot + $ele.innerHeight() - settings.stickyBottom) * -1);
     }
     else{
      $ele.css('top', settings.stickyTop);
     }  
    }
    else{
     $ele.removeAttr('style').removeClass(settings.stickyClass);
    }
   }
   r();
   $(window).scroll(f);
   $(window).resize(function(){
    $ele.removeAttr('style');
    r();
   });
  });
 }

}(jQuery));
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.sidebar1').sticky({
  stickyClass: 'sticky',
  widthLimit: 767
 });
 $('.sidebar2').sticky({
  stickyTop: 50,
  stickyBottom: -50,
  stickyClass: 'sticky',
  widthLimit: 767
 });
 $('.sidebar3').sticky({
  stickyTop: 50,
  stickyBottom: 70,
  stickyClass: 'sticky',
  widthLimit: 767
 });
 $('.sidebar4').sticky({
  stickyTop: 0,
  stickyBottom: 70,
  stickyClass: 'sticky',
  widthLimit: 767
 });
 $('.sidebar5').sticky({
  stickyTop: 0,
  stickyBottom: 0,
  stickyClass: 'sticky',
  widthLimit: 767,
  stickyParent: '.parent-sticky'
 });
});
```

```css
html {
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; /* Prevent font scaling in landscape */
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
h1, h2, h4 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
*, *:after, *:before{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Work Sans', serif;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 50px 0;    
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 background: #DD5E89; 
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #F7BB97, #DD5E89); 
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #F7BB97, #DD5E89); 
}
.container{
 max-width: 960px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0 15px;
 margin: auto;
}
.title{
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.title:after{
 content: '';
 width: 50px;
 height: 4px;
 background: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}
.main-title .title{
 margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.main-title .title:after{
 margin: auto;
 right: 0;
 width: 100px;
}
h1{
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
 font-size: 55px;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 500;
 text-align: center;
}
h2{
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
 font-size: 40px;
}
h4{
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: 500;
 color: #1d1d1d;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.content-wrap{
 padding: 25px 25px 40px;
 background-color: #8647db;
 border-radius: 4px;
 color: #fff;
}
.text-wrap p{
 line-height: 26px;
 font-weight: 300;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
.btn-wrap{
 padding-top: 25px;
}
.btn-wrap a{
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 24px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 color: #6231a6;
 font-weight: 500;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 3px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.sidebar{
 background: #fff;
 padding: 25px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
.sidebar ul{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}
.my-list li{
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 24px;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #6231a6;
 padding: 8px 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-transform: translate(150%, 0px);
 -moz-transform: translate(150%, 0px);
 -o-transform: translate(150%, 0px);
 -ms-transform: translate(150%, 0px);
 transform: translate(150%, 0px);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.my-list li:last-child{
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.my-list.rev li{
 -webkit-transform: translate(-150%, 0px);
 -moz-transform: translate(-150%, 0px);
 -o-transform: translate(-150%, 0px);
 -ms-transform: translate(-150%, 0px);
 transform: translate(-150%, 0px);
}
.my-list li:nth-child(1){
 transition-delay: 0.05s;
}
.my-list li:nth-child(2){
 transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.my-list li:nth-child(3){
 transition-delay: 0.15s;
}
.my-list li:nth-child(4){
 transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.sidebar.sticky .my-list li{
 -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
 -moz-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
 -o-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
 -ms-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
 transform: translate(0%, 0px);
}
.tags{
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}
ul.tags-wrap{
 margin-left: -3px;
 margin-right: -3px;
}
.tags-wrap li{
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 16px;
 color: #fff;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background-color: #36a631;
 padding: 5px 8px;
 margin: 3px;
}
.tags-wrap li.red{
 background-color: #de2342;
}
.main-container{
 margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.parent-sticky > .container{
 margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.parent-sticky > .container:last-child{
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
@media(max-width: 1024px){
 .sidebar.sidebar1 .my-list li,
 .sidebar.sidebar1 .my-list.rev li{
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  transform: translate(0%, 0px);
 }
}
@media(max-width: 991px){
 .sidebar.sidebar2 .my-list li,
 .sidebar.sidebar2 .my-list.rev li{
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  transform: translate(0%, 0px);
 }
}
@media(max-width: 767px){
 h1{
  font-size: 50px;
 }
 .sidebar{
  margin-top: 25px;
 }
 .sidebar .my-list li,
 .sidebar .my-list.rev li{
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  transform: translate(0%, 0px);
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="main-container">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="content-wrap">
     <div class="title">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="text-wrap">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</p>
     </div>
     <div class="btn-wrap">
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="sidebar sidebar1">
     <div class="tags">
      <h4>Sticky Properties</h4>
      <ul class="tags-wrap d-flex flex-wrap">
       <li>Top : 0</li>
       <li>Bottom : 0</li>
       <li>WidthLimit : 1024px</li>
       <li>StickyClass : sticky</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <ul class="my-list">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="main-container">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row flex-row-reverse">
   <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="content-wrap">
     <div class="title">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="text-wrap">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</p>
     </div>
     <div class="btn-wrap">
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="sidebar sidebar2">
     <div class="tags">
      <h4>Sticky Properties</h4>
      <ul class="tags-wrap d-flex flex-wrap">
       <li>Top : 50</li>
       <li>Bottom : 50</li>
       <li>WidthLimit : 991px</li>
       <li>StickyClass : sticky</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <ul class="my-list rev">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="main-container">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="content-wrap">
     <div class="title">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="text-wrap">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</p>
     </div>
     <div class="btn-wrap">
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="sidebar sidebar3">
     <div class="tags">
      <h4>Sticky Properties</h4>
      <ul class="tags-wrap d-flex flex-wrap">
       <li>Top : 50</li>
       <li class="red">Bottom : -70</li>
       <li>WidthLimit : 767px</li>
       <li>StickyClass : sticky</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <ul class="my-list">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="main-container">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row flex-row-reverse">
   <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="content-wrap">
     <div class="title">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="text-wrap">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</p>
     </div>
     <div class="btn-wrap">
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="sidebar sidebar4">
     <div class="tags">
      <h4>Sticky Properties</h4>
      <ul class="tags-wrap d-flex flex-wrap">
       <li>Top : 0</li>
       <li class="red">Bottom : -70</li>
       <li>WidthLimit : 767px</li>
       <li>StickyClass : sticky</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <ul class="my-list rev">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="main-container parent-sticky">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="content-wrap">
     <div class="title">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="text-wrap">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</p>
     </div>
     <div class="btn-wrap">
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="sidebar sidebar5">
     <div class="tags">
      <h4>Sticky Properties</h4>
      <ul class="tags-wrap d-flex flex-wrap">
       <li>Top : 50</li>
       <li>Bottom : 0</li>
       <li>WidthLimit : 767px</li>
       <li>StickyClass : sticky</li>
       <li>StickyParent : '.parent-sticky'</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <ul class="my-list">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="content-wrap">
     <div class="title">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="text-wrap">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</p>
     </div>
     <div class="btn-wrap">
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="main-container">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="content-wrap">
   <div class="title">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="text-wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</p>
   </div>
   <div class="btn-wrap">
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: wow, that's pretty cool. i'll definitely use this too, thanks!